# Please recommend a resource for set / relations / functions questions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, book-recommendation

I had done a course in logic and have a basic idea about indirect reasoning, can you recommend me a textbook containing only important questions which are indirect reasoning based questions?

Comment: You mean a book that shows a good introduction to elementary set theory?

Comment: I want important questions .can you recommend some online material or textbook on elementary set theory.

Comment: I think I can help you, but first let me know what do you know about mathematical logic and elementary set theory. Depending on your answer, I will be able to provide you with some good material to work with

Comment: I need to practice lengthy proofs,those involving subderivations and assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to become familiar with the mathematical reasoning and the basic ideas behind set theory, you can start by something more informal / intuitive.

I strongly recommend the book “*Proofs and Fundamentals*”, by Ethan D. Bloch. It has a really nice introduction to these topics and he really focus on the way one should write proofs.

After that, if you really want something more mature about set theory, I recommend the classic “*Naive Set Theory*” by Paul R. Halos.